How to add typing for a file extension in a npm package?
I'm writing a webpack loader which for the example here processes *.foo files. I want to create typescript typings for it as follows:
// index.d.ts

declare module "*.foo" {
   const bar: string;
   export default bar;
}

I'd like to publish this loader as a npm package foo-loader and when someone adds a dependency to foo-loader, I would like it to resolve import foobar from './foo.bar'; as a string like declared above. I currently cannot get it to work.
I've tried adding the module declaration in my index.d.ts file which is referenced in my package.json:
// package.json

{
   "types": "index.d.ts"
}

in addition i've tried adding foo-loader into the types option in ts-config.json with no success.
How do I get it so that my d.ts file gets read automatically once it's added as a dependency. Is it possible to do so without an @types/... package?
